# how secure is a web hosting company that only uses no ssl - only ftp

Tags: security, ftp, web-hosting

I'm looking at using a free hosting company short term (not sure if I should mention names) but they don't offer sftp and the cpanel is http not https. They appear to be a reasonable company, I've used them for a few years for low security sites, just only provide ssl for paid accounts.

It's a php web app for a company that's going live shortly and I need to get if off my computer and onto something that can provide better up-time while they do data entry and I do some extra coding.

What are the chances of a breach? Am I treading on thin ice, or is it not actually that dangerous?

Excuse my probably noob questions, it's for my last university project and I'm feeling like I'm kinda in the deep end here lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used them for a few years and haven't been breached yet, what do you think the likelihood of it happening now is?  Do you think that this site will be higher profile than your past sites and thus be more likely to attract unwanted attention?

On the other hand if this client of yours is or could be paying you and expects reliability/security, or if the implications of a breach are significant (sensitive data) why not pay for peace of mind?

If you want to go ahead with the free service, just make sure that you're shipping frequent (non-overwriting) data backups off-site so you can recover in any eventuality.

Comment: It's more higher stakes than risk I think, when it's a site for a family member you don't care so much...
Only admins will be given links, but if a bot manages to find it I don't want to give away all my php and the database. It's not super sensitive, like financial records, but data (albeit in a state of half completion) that the company will make money off.